# In WebRTC, which ICE candidate created a successful connection?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I want to know which ICE candidate created a successful connection and is being used to transfer data between peers. I want to be able to differentiate a local (host) connection from a server reflexive to a TURN connection.

I am currently using the WebRTC native API and don't see any public APIs that allow me to know which ICE candidate successfully created a connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the getStats API. The process is similar to the one described [here](https://testrtc.com/find-webrtc-active-connection/)

Comment: Thank you. Finding report types of "googCandidatePair" who have a key of "googActiveConnection" and a value of true